# Microsoft Graph Exception: New password credentials must be generated using service actions

Tags: c#, .net-core, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

How do I use the Microsoft Graph Client SDK to add a client secret when creating an Application?

Defining an Application like below fails with a *New password credentials must be generated using service actions.* exception:

```cs
var application new Application
{
    DisplayName = "My app name",
    PasswordCredentials = new List<PasswordCredential>
    {
        new PasswordCredential
        {
            SecretText = secretKey,
            DisplayName = "Default Secret",
            EndDateTime = DateTimeOffset.MaxValue,
            KeyId = Guid.NewGuid(),
            StartDateTime = DateTimeOffset.Now,
            CustomKeyIdentifier = null,
            Hint = secretKey.Substring(4)
        }
    }
};

await graphClient.Applications.Request().AddAsync(application);
```

I've found information on how to do this using HTTP POST, but not when using the Microsoft Graph client SDK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it, just had to look harder in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-addpassword?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#request).

```cs
var createdApplication = await graphClient.Applications.Request().AddAsync(application);

var passwordCredential = new PasswordCredential
{
    DisplayName = "Password friendly name",
    EndDateTime = DateTimeOffset.Parse("31/12/2299"), // Max allowed as far as I can tell
    KeyId = Guid.NewGuid(),
    StartDateTime = DateTimeOffset.Now,
    CustomKeyIdentifier = null,
};

var passwordCredential = await graphClient.Applications[createdApplication.Id]
    .AddPassword(passwordCredential)
    .Request()
    .PostAsync();
```

The return value `passwordCredential` holds the secret text.

Answer (score 2):

You can not add the passwordCredentials: []directectly to the application creation POST call. You'll get the error similar to this: New password credentials must be generated using service actions. You have to first create the application and then making a POST call to update the application's passwordCredentials field. With this change you cannot generate your own secret text anymore. You can only set the start date, end date, and displayname.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-addpassword?view=graph-rest-beta